# Youtube API error "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup" from Google Cloud Platform VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, youtube-api

I've added an API Key for my project and I'm trying to retrieve data via URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails%2Cstatistics&id={VIDEO_ID}&key={MY_KEY}
```

When I try it in my browser, I get the response:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"{ETAG}\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"{ETAG}\"",
   "id": "{VIDEO_ID}",
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT3M11S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "sd",
    "caption": "false",
    "licensedContent": false,
    "projection": "rectangular"
   },
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "12822",
    "likeCount": "44",
    "dislikeCount": "0",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "4"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

But it doesn't work from my Google Cloud Virtual Machine, I get an error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

This API key is unrestricted.

What is wrong? How to fix it?

Comment: It's literally what the error says: _Daily limit for **unauthenticated use** exceeded. Continued use **requires signup**._

Comment: @Edric, but I still can retrive data from my local computer.

Comment: @adrenalin this same error happens when you're authenticated? - `from your local computer` = doesn't says whether you were logged or not. clarify this in your question. if the isuse persists, use [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues).